# Deserialize a JSON to a List<SObject>

Tags: apex, sobject, object, schema

I have an Apex class which has a method having an Object type parameter

```
public with sharing class DmlOnSObjectRecords {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static void dmlOperationOnSObjectRecords(Object data) {
    List<SObject> recordsForUpdate = (List<SObject>) JSON.deserialize(
        JSON.serialize(data),
        List<SObject>.class         
    );
    try {
        upsert recordsForUpdate;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
   }
 }
```

The parameter given is a JSON in the following format

```
 {"Id":"0036F00003gZDJQQA4","FirstName":"Madhurima"}
```

My problem here is that, the deserialization is throwing me an error

```
 Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.
```

I also tried deserializing in the following format

```
 Map <String, Object> result = (Map <String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(dataString);
```

But this also throws an error

```
 Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to Map<String,ANY>
```

I don't want to hard code the type during deserialization because, I want to keep it as a dynamic component.

Also I don't want to use a wrapper class because, then I will have to hard code the paramter fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the type also as a parameter and then deserialize it based on that.

Also pass a string using `JSON.stringify` in the `strJSONdata` from UI.

Something like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void dmlOperationOnSObjectRecords(String strJSONData, String strType, Boolean boolIsList) {
    List<SObject> lstObjects = new List<SObject>();
    if (boolIsList) {
        lstObjects = (List<SObject>) JSON.deserialize(strJSONData, Type.forName(strType));
    } else {
        SObject obj = (SObject) JSON.deserialize(strJSONData, Type.forName(strType));
        lstObjects.add(obj);
    }
    System.debug(lstObjects.size());
    System.debug(lstObjects);
}
```

---

Anonymous apex:

```
YourClassName.dmlOperationOnSObjectRecords('{"Id":"0036F00003gZDJQQA4","FirstName":"Madhurima"}', 'Contact', false);

YourClassName.dmlOperationOnSObjectRecords('[{"Id":"0036F00003gZDJQQA4","FirstName":"Madhurima"}]', 'List<Contact>', true);
```

Comment: This works, though I would have preferred fetching the Object Type from the record Ids themselves instead of passing the Object type from the js file. Is there absolutely no way to achieve that? @NagendraSingh

Comment: Yes there is, but in that case, you need to pass the ID separately instead of the Object Type. `Id.valueOf('YOUR_RECORD_ID').getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName()`

Comment: hmm, I am actually passing it from a lwc datable, so the only thing I can pass is an Object. No way to separate the editable Ids.

Comment: I dont think you, you still can, you can just do JSON.stringyfy / JSON.parse and do `.Id`, that should given you the Id from the row.